# Batch text search with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, pg-search

I have a Rails 4 app with PostgreSQL database. I use PSQL default full text search for some fields, such as university_name. I need to send hundreds of full text search query at a time against my database.

Right now, I perform these queries serially, and it is very slow. Is there any way I can send text search in batch mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes try using the `tsvector columns` which will

[pg_search#using-tsvector-columns](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#using-tsvector-columns)

Later you will run the search against the tsv_field instead of the normal text, which will make it faster.

```
pg_search_scope :fast_content_search,
                :against => :content,
                :using => {
                  dmetaphone: {
                    tsvector_column: 'tsvector_content_dmetaphone'
                  },
                  tsearch: {
                    dictionary: 'english',
                    tsvector_column: 'tsvector_content_tsearch'
                  }
                  trigram: {} # trigram does not use tsvectors
                }
```